# Add Ubuntu on to Windows Server 2012 Active Directory

Tags: 14.04

I am having trouble adding Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Client to Windows Server 2012's Active Directory. I have tried to configure **Samba, Likewise, Realmd, SSSD & Winbind** in ubuntu but nothing seems to work.
Please Help!

Thanks :)

Comment: In what way does nothing work?

Comment: In other words, I mean like the configuration always give errors.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what issues you had with the other methods.  However you might want to check out PBIS Open:

```
http://download1.beyondtrust.com/Technical-Support/Downloads/PowerBroker-Identity-Services-Open-Edition/?Pass=True
```

The installation and set up is very straightforward if you follow their documentation.

Cheers.